# $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ maps $\mathbb R$ onto $[1, \infty)$

Tags: functions

> Let $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ and $x$ in $\mathbb R$. Prove that $f$ maps $\mathbb R$ onto $[1, \infty)$.

Let $\mathbb R$ be the domain of $f$ and $[1, \infty$) the codomain of $f$.  Then $f$ maps $\mathbb R$ into $[1, \infty)$. Let $f(\mathbb R)$ be the  range of $f$.  Then $f(\mathbb R)$ is the set of positive reals. So, $[1, \infty) \subseteq f(\mathbb R)$. Since $x$ is real and $f(x) = x^2$, then $f(x) > 0$, so $f(x)$ is in $[1, \infty)$. Thus the range of $f$ equals the codomain of $f$: f($\mathbb R$) = $[1, \infty)$. Therefore, $f$ maps $\mathbb R$ onto $[1, \infty)$.

Does the proof work?

Comment: It is true to say that $f(x)=x^2+1 \geq1 $for all $x\in \mathbb R$. But is this equivalent to say that $f(\mathbb R)$ "covers" all $[1, \infty)$?

Comment: "Then $f(\mathbb R)$ is the set of positive reals." - No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As first the formulation is pretty wrong "Then $f(\mathbb{R})$ is a set of positive reals" how did you conclude that?You could have written Since for real $x$ inequality holds $x^2\geq 0$ from this we may conclude $x^2+1\geq1$ since $x^2$ can take all the values in $\mathbb{R^+}$ it follows that $x^2+1$ can take all the values of $[1,\infty)$.

Anyway I would suggest a simpler approach if we can express $x$ using $f(x)$ than the function is onto.
$$y=x^2+1\\x^2=y-1\\x=\sqrt{y-1}$$
Since $y\geq0$,for every $y=f(x)$ there is a corresponding $x=\sqrt{f(x)-1}$